# Meaning of "To determine"

Tags: vocabulary

Can the verb "to determine" be understood as "make some operations in order to find something".
Ex: "The computer determines the value of the expression"

Comment: It can be.  But there are several other meanings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can -- see meaning #4:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/determine

> > 4:  to find out or come to a decision about by investigation, reasoning, or calculation
> >
> > 'determine the answer to the problem'
> >
> > 'determine a position at sea'